# Code for increasing RPM of a DC motor proportionally to the Temperature input in Arduino

Tags: arduino

So i have this circuit in TinkerCad [image: tinkercad arduino]

that turns the dc motor on and off depending on the input of the temperature in TMP. How do i make it so that instead of turning the DC motor on and off, it instead increases the rpm as the temperature input goes higher? so far i have this code:

```
int sensorPin = 0;
 
void setup()
{
 pinMode(A0,INPUT);
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop()
{
 
 int reading = analogRead(sensorPin);
 float voltage = reading * 5;
 voltage /= 1024.0;
 
 float celsius = (voltage - 0.5) * 100;
 Serial.print(celsius);
 Serial.println(" degrees C");
 if (celsius < 30) {
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
   
  }
  
  if (celsius > 30)
  {
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    
  }
  
  delay(10); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analogWrite to send a PWM-Signal to the L293D.

```
analogWrite(outputPin, map(analogRead(inputPin), 0, 1023, 0, 255); //outputPin needs to be a PWM-Pin
```

References: [analogWrite()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/), [map()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/)